# VBS send mouse clicks?

Tags: vbscript, click

I need send mouse clicks from VBS. Like SendKeys. I have searched whole google, it seems there is no such function for VBS. Can you give me some solution?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a routine to send a left or right click to a window (using relative references) in VBA for Excel.  Similar to AppActivate, you just need the window title.

The arguments when you call the **SendClick** routine are:

- Window Title (String)
- Buttons (1 = Left, 2 = Right, -1 = Move mouse only; no click)
- x (Relative position to window Left)
- y (Relative position to window Top)

Enjoy!

```
'Declare mouse events
Public Declare Function SetCursorPos Lib "user32" (ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long) As Long
Public Declare Sub mouse_event Lib "user32" (ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dx As Long, ByVal dy As Long, ByVal cButtons As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Long)
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = &H2
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = &H4
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN As Long = &H8
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP As Long = &H10
'Declare sleep
Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)

' Window location
Public Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
Public Declare Function GetWindowRect Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As Long, lpRect As RECT) As Long
Type RECT
  Left As Long
  Top As Long
  Right As Long
  Bottom As Long
End Type

Public Function WindowHandle(ByVal sTitle As String) As Long
    WindowHandle = FindWindow(vbNullString, sTitle)
End Function

Public Sub SendClick(sWnd As String, b As Integer, x As Long, y As Long)
    Dim pWnd As Long, pRec As RECT

    pWnd = WindowHandle(sWnd)
    GetWindowRect pWnd, pRec

    SetCursorPos pRec.Left + x, pRec.Top + y
    Sleep 50
    If b = 2 Then
        mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0
        Sleep 50
        mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0
    ElseIf b <> -1 Then
        mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0
        Sleep 50
        mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible with VBScript alone. You'll need to use a third-party tool like [nircmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html). You can use its `setcursor`, `setcursorwin`, `movecursor`, and `sendmouse` commands to manipulate the mouse.

For example, here's how to move the cursor to a screen coordinate (measured from the top left) and perform a right-click:

```
With CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    .Run "nircmd setcursor 100 100", 0, True
    .Run "nircmd sendmouse right click", 0, True
End With
```

See the [documentation](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd2.html#sendmouse) for parameter information.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 Dim x
 set x=createobject("wscript.shell")

 x.sendkeys"{CLICK LEFT,50,60}"
```

or

```
 x.SendKeys("+{F10}") 'for a right click
```

If neither of those work for you I would suggest using something like [Autoit](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) or [autohotkey](https://autohotkey.com/), using AutoHotKey you could write a macro that does the clicking and then call the script from your VBScript.

Answer (score 0):

VBS is a script, not an application; VBScripts can call other applications or *Component Objects* to access elements of the host environment, just like batch files; eg. `FileSystemObject` to manipulate files.

There isn't one provided for mouse, so to move mouse or send mouse clicks, you'd need to call some app or COM object to do it, or make one.
Some apps that can manipulate the mouse are MSWord & MSExcel (via WinAPI calls), NirCmd, AutoIt, AutoHotKey, etc

Here's a VBApp example that calls functions of the *User Component*: `user32.dll`:

(Notice how the arguments are formatted before being sent to the DLL. This is not possible in VBS or batch files since they can only pass Strings as args; some functions expect data types eg. Int32, window handles or object references)

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On
Option Infer On

Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class Mousing
    Private Declare Auto Sub mouse_event Lib "user32" (ByVal dwFlags As Int32, ByVal dx As Int32, ByVal dy As Int32, ByVal cButtons As Int32, ByVal dwExtraInfo As IntPtr)
    Private Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN As Int32 = &H2
    Private Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP As Int32 = &H4
    Private Const MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN As Long = &H8
    Private Const MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP As Long = &H10


    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)>
    Private Structure RECT
        Public Left As Integer
        Public Top As Integer
        Public Right As Integer
        Public Bottom As Integer
    End Structure

    <DllImport("user32.dll")> _
    Private Shared Function GetWindowRect(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByRef lpRect As RECT) As Boolean
    End Function

    <DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, EntryPoint:="FindWindow")> _
    Private Shared Function FindWindow(ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As IntPtr
    End Function

    <DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError:=True, ExactSpelling:=True)> _
    Private Shared Function SetForegroundWindow(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> Boolean
    End Function

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        ' find the window 
        Dim hWnd As IntPtr = FindWindow(Nothing, "Some Window")
        ' check if window found
        If hWnd.Equals(IntPtr.Zero) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Window Not Found!", "Aborting", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
            Return ' exit
        Else
            ' bring the window to the foreground
            SetForegroundWindow(hWnd)

            ' get the windows size and location
            Dim r As New RECT
            GetWindowRect(hWnd, r)

            'Move the cursor to the windows location plus our offset (x + 50 , y + 100)
            Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position = New System.Drawing.Point(r.Left + 50, r.Top + 100)
        ' To move relative to screen, just enter coordinates above without offsetting

           ' click the left mouse button at the current mouse position
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN + MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, IntPtr.Zero)
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

The following is a VBScript calling AutoIt to move mouse & click:

```
Set oAutoIt = WScript.CreateObject("AutoItX.Control")
set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
oAutoIt.MouseMove x,y,0
WScript.Sleep 500
oAutoIt.MouseClick($MOUSE_CLICK_PRIMARY)
```

References:
http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?672196-RESOLVED-SetCursorPos
http://www.ericphelps.com/batch/rundll/
https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=3931
https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/152969/visual-basic-procedure-to-get-set-cursor-position
https://microsoft.public.scripting.vbscript.narkive.com/ZO09Cxnz/moving-mouse-pointer-with-vbs-file