# How to left click in VBScript

Tags: vbscript, sendkeys

I have a problem trying to do a click with SendKeys in VBScript.

I have this code:

```
Set Click = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WScript.Sleep 7000
Click.SendKeys ("{CLICK LEFT, 1165, 623}")
WScript.Sleep 300
WshShell.SendKeys ("{ENTER}")
```

I have tried also with: `Click.SendKeys "{CLICK LEFT, 1165, 623}"`  but doesn´t work

This is the error that appears when the script arrives to the click (line 74):

[image]

Comment: That's not vbscript, although looks similar. Its Automate. You can't click with vbscript.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36337966/2237785

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VBS send mouse clicks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36310246/vbs-send-mouse-clicks)