# Send Keystroke to Adobe Reader DC to Update

Tags: wsh, wscript.shell

Is there a way to send keystroke to adobe reader DC using script to initiate Update ,

Please help.
Thank you

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow.  Anyways, you might find an answer [here] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36310246/vbs-send-mouse-clicks).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VBS send mouse clicks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36310246/vbs-send-mouse-clicks)